# If-Else Sproc & Calling multi parameter SProc in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Fairly new to Stored Procedure within SSRS.

I have worked on numerous reports having parameters passed directly within SSRS dataset nut this is a bit new to me and seems like I am getting a bit confused.

I got a requirement to merge 2 reports with exactly same layout and then execute the report based on a dropdown selection from SSRS.

My Stored Procedure is something like below.

---

```
USE [ReportsDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_WithoutExternalReferences]
(
    @XNumber INT,
    @YNumber INT
)   
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF (@XNumber = NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            adviser_account.adviser_account_id,
            dealer.old_system_reference,
            external_reference.external_reference AS Missing_refernce,
            entity.name AS Name,
            entity.given_names As Given_Names,
            entity_address.property_name,
        FROM Composer_adviser_account AS adviser_account
        INNER JOIN Composer_entity AS entity
        ON adviser_account.entity_id = entity.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN Composer_party_external_reference AS external_reference
        ON adviser_account.adviser_account_id = external_reference.party_id  
        WHERE
            external_reference.party_type_id = 3
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@YNumber = NULL)
            BEGIN
                SELECT 
                    dealer.dealer_id,
                    dealer.old_system_reference,
                    dealer.fsa_firm_reference_id as Missing_refernce,
                    entity.name AS Name,
                    entity.given_names AS Given_Names,
                    entity_address.property_name,
                FROM Composer_dealer AS dealer
                INNER JOIN Composer_entity AS entity
                ON dealer.entity_id = entity.entity_id
                INNER JOIN Composer_address AS entity_address
                ON entity.entity_id = entity_address.entity_id
                WHERE dealer.fsa_firm_reference_id IS NULL
            END
        END
    END
END
```

---

Now, I want to call this Stored Procedure from SSRS, where Users can either select XNumber Null or YNumber NULL and then the corresponding portion of the code runs.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Notice your `NULL` comparison: you must use `IS` keyword, and should make your input parameters optional:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_WithoutExternalReferences]
(
    @XNumber INT = NULL,
    @YNumber INT = NULL
)   
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF ((@XNumber IS NULL AND YNumber IS NULL) OR
        (@XNumber IS NOT NULL AND YNumber IS NOT NULL))
        RAISERROR('Invalid arguments', 16, 1);

    IF (@XNumber IS NULL) BEGIN

        SELECT      adviser_account.adviser_account_id
                    ,dealer.old_system_reference 
                    ,external_reference.external_reference AS Missing_refernce
                    ,entity.name AS Name
                    ,entity.given_names As Given_Names
                    ,entity_address.property_name 
        FROM        Composer_adviser_account AS adviser_account
        INNER JOIN  Composer_entity AS entity
                ON  adviser_account.entity_id = entity.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN   Composer_party_external_reference AS external_reference
                ON  adviser_account.adviser_account_id = external_reference.party_id  
        WHERE       external_reference.party_type_id = 3

    END ELSE IF (@YNumber IS NULL) BEGIN

        SELECT      dealer.dealer_id 
                    ,dealer.old_system_reference 
                    ,dealer.fsa_firm_reference_id as Missing_refernce
                    ,entity.name AS Name
                    ,entity.given_names AS Given_Names
                    ,entity_address.property_name 
        FROM        Composer_dealer AS dealer
        INNER JOIN  Composer_entity AS entity
                ON  dealer.entity_id = entity.entity_id
        INNER JOIN  Composer_address AS entity_address
                ON  entity.entity_id = entity_address.entity_id
        WHERE       dealer.fsa_firm_reference_id IS NULL

    END

END
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens, much appreciated ! Any help with calling this Sproc from SSRS and then users can either select XNumber as Null OR YNumber as NULL and then the corresponding portin of the code runs.

Comment: `exec rpt_WithoutExternalReferences NULL, 123; exec rpt_WithoutExternalReferences 123, NULL;` ?

Comment: Thanks Ruben,But the users can either select XNumber as Null or YNumber as Null and cant select Both NULLs at the same time.  Not sure if I am framing my question rightly here, sorry if its confusing you even more !

Comment: Seems you just an `IF` statement: if both are `NULL` (or both non `NULL`) use `RAISEERROR` to stop execution

Comment: Sorry Ruben, clueless as to where to use this IF statement.